# mCustomScrollbar not working on jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my html i am trying to update the cart data via ajax calls.
In html

```
<div id="cart_list"></div>
```

And inside script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.get("/show_header/",
          function(data) {
          show_cart(data)
         });

})
```

And this is the show_cart function

```
function show_cart(data){
     $("#cart_list").append(
        '<div  class="dropdown  cartMenu ">'+
        '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>'+
        '<div class="dropdown-menu col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 " style="width: 184%;">'+
        '<div id="scroll_cart" class="w100 miniCartTable scroll-pane">'+
        '<table>'+
        '<tbody>'+
        cart_string+
        '</tbody>'+
        '</table>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="miniCartFooter text-right">'+
        '<h3 class="text-right subtotal"> Subtotal:₹ '+ data.header_data.price +' </h3>'+
        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/cart/"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"> </i> VIEW CART </a>'+
        '<a href="/payment/" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> CHECKOUT </a> </div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'
      )
    }
```

(cart_string is generated inside function show_cart. But i removed those steps since i think its not relevant here).

But the scrollbar is not working anymore. I tried the other answers in this section and nothing seems to work.

I tried giving the div with the scroll class an id "scroll_cart" and tried the following line inside show_cart function. But no change.

```
$("#scroll_cart").mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

What is the right way to enable scrollbar for the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$("#scroll_cart").mCustomScrollbar("update");` after creating the elements.

ie, after `show_cart()` function.

Because the element `$("#scroll_cart")` should be present on the dom at the time of binding.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get("/show_header/",
        function(data) {
            show_cart(data);
            $("#scroll_cart").mCustomScrollbar("update");
        });

})
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.get("/show_header/",
          function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          show_cart(data)
          $("#scroll_cart").mCustomScrollbar("update");
         });

})

I did like this.But no change

Comment: $(".scroll-pane").mCustomScrollbar.... Its used in another script in the page . Is that why ?

Comment: did you refer jquery and the required scripts in your page?

Comment: Yes . i removed those two functions from script.js and added after the showcart call and now it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please see this [reference](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/228#issuecomment-304718085)

codes:

```
  $('#scroll_cart').mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
  $('#scroll_cart').append('some text');
  $('#scroll_cart').mCustomScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure in your HTML file you have included **jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js**